# Auto generate constructor with default initialization of variables

Tags: java, eclipse

This might be a super-lame lazy question.

Is it possible to generate constructor in Eclipse like

```
class A{
    int a;
    String b;
    float c;

    /* Is it possible to auto-generate this*/
    public A() {
        a = 0;
        b = "";
        c = 0f; 
    }
 }
```

I am aware that default initialization would any case take care of this but I need a code auto-generated like this so that I can change the default value of say int as 5 and float as 3 and so on.

If this is not available then the next best option would be generate constructor using fields and then converting it to this.

Comment: If you have to change all the values anyway, creating it yourself would be as quick. Note that a and c initializations are redendant here, but not b (a String's default value is null, and not "").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, set the fields when you declare them:

```
class A{
    int a = 9;
    String b = "";
    float c = 0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default values in the field *declarations*:

```
class A {
  private int a = 3;
  private String b = "asdf";
  private float c = 3;
  ...
}
```

But if you expect *clients* to provide values, then its better to accept them as constructor parameters:

```
public A() { } // default constructor will use the values in the fields
public A(int a, String b, int c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. Because, as you said, you don't need it. Primitives are initialized to that anyway - if you want to change them, do so. And eclipse can't know what's the default value for non-primitives.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way for what you are trying to achieve but YES there is a way to auto-generate constructor based on the fields in your class.

In Eclipse, Go to...

> Source / Generate Constructor using Fields...

...and then you can select fields, which you want to initialize and then change the default values and parameters of constructor.

> Note: For your solution, select the fields which you want to initialize and then remove them from constructor's parameters, so it will become *Constructor with no parameters*.

For more info, visit this link.
http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/03/08/generate-class-constructors-in-eclipse-based-on-fields-or-superclass-constructors/